# Does the series $\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\log \log n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\log \log n}$ converge ?

I thought about alternating test, but for some reason this seems to easy. Why does it start with $n=4$? And how do I prove that $\frac1{\log \log n}$ is decreasing ?

Comment: You could start it at another $n>1$ (So $\ln \ln n$ is defined.)

Comment: And why would "too easy" be a problem?  $\log \log n$ is real for $n \ge 4$, right?

Comment: What is wrong with easy?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, but normally they start with $n=1$, I thought there must be a reason... but maybe not

Comment: log is increasing. We also need limit of our terms is $0$. Everything admittedly easy, but there are a few things to mention. And $\log 1=0$, so $\log\log 1$ is a problem. So is $\log\log 2$. They could have started at $3$. Or $17$.

Comment: Well, $1$ would be a problem.  What is $\log\log 1$ ... ?

Comment: Why would $\ln \ln 2$ be a problem? Negativity ain't bad...

Comment: @copper.hat From $n=3$ the sequence is decreasing. I think this is what Andre Nicolas means.

Comment: It doesn't matter what happens in the first 42 terms...

Comment: Yeah, that is true.. But in my book the theorem is stated as if it does matter. But I know it easily proven that it doesn't.

Comment: It converges, but **ridiculously** slowly.

Comment: @Kasper: I actually meant that the term at $2$ and at $3$ have the same sign. It is only alternating from $3$ on. Not that this matters.

Answer (score 7):

It is an alternating series of terms that diminish monotonically with limit 0, so it converges. It doesn't converge absolutely because its terms are larger than $1 /n$.

Answer (score 4):

With the derivative $(\log(\log x))'=\dfrac{1}{x\log(x)}>0$ so the function is increasing for $x>1$, so the sequence $\dfrac{1}{\log(\log n)}$ is decreasing to $0$ and the alternating test is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

It really is that easy. If $f(x)$ is increasing, then $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is decreasing. The denominator of the sequence is increasing. You can check using the first derivative test that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln( \ln x) >0$ (Note: the sequence $\ln(\ln n)$ is increasing if the function $\ln(\ln x)$ is increasing). Thus, the original sequence is increasing. Alternatively, you can use induction.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Sorry. Changed iff to if. Thanks.